# Prime-ng p-checkbox [ngModel]="shouldShowValue(group, user)" selected value can not be determined via a function

Tags: angular, checkbox, primeng

Here are the rows of my p-table

```
<tr>
            <td>{{user.userName}}</td>
            <td>{{use.userSurname}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let group of groups"><p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="showValue(group, user)" [binary]="true" (change)="setSelectedValue(group, user)"></p-checkbox></td>
          </tr>
```

if I use a normal checkbox instead of a p-checkbox [checked]="showValue(group, permission) works as expected

It appears I can not pass [(ngModel)] a function to determine if it should be checked or not, can someone assist me with alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you handle the `change` event already, it's not necessary to handle the `ngModelChange` event (which is what [parenthesis](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#two-way-binding) mean in `[(ngModel)]`), so:

```html
<p-checkbox
  [binary]="true"
  [ngModel]="showValue(group, user)"
  (change)="setSelectedValue(group, user)"
></p-checkbox>
```